# Python count 0-9 then a-z

Tags: python, loops

I'm attempting to build a style sheet with this structure:

```
.something-[content_name]:before {
  content: '[unicode_string]';
}
```

For the style sheet, the Unicode string follows the pattern:

```
/f[0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z]
```

And a set of SVGs with this structure:

```
<glyph unicode="[unicode_string]" d="some_path" />
```

I have a list of things that I'm going to be inserting as content, and I need a way to iterate through and assign unicode values to the content.

I want to iterate through 0-9 then a-z (lowercase only) in each place before moving to the next, resulting in:

```
&#xf000, &#xf001, &#xf002 ... &#xf009
&#xf00a, &#xf00b, &#xf00c ... &#xf00z
&#xf010, &#xf011, &#xf012 ... &#xf019, &#xf01a, &#xf01b, &#xf01c ... &#xf01z
&#xf0a0, &#xf0b1, &#xf0 ... &#xf019, &#xf01a, &#xf01b, &#xf01c ... &#xf01z
```

Substituting `/` for `&#x` isn't an issue, I just want to know the best way to iterate through this way.

Comment: Hex digits are 0-9 a-f not 0-9 a-z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for itertools.product?

```
import string, itertools


for p in itertools.product(string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=3):
    print '&#xf' + ''.join(p)
```

For hex numbers, simply iterate over `0123456789abcdef`:

```
for p in itertools.product('0123456789abcdef', repeat=3):
```

Comment: he wants all letters.

Comment: I'm actually trying to get all the combinations in the range of a list (ie. I want to assign unicode values to the PUA for creating an icon set font à la fontawesome).